# How to avoid double encoding when URLSearchParams Web API is used?

Tags: javascript, html, api, encoding, urlencode

I've been using URLSearchParams to simplify url params which are appened to my URL. I've written a helper function which would return the params:-

```js
const getUrlParams = (page, pagesize, search) => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams({
        page,
        pagesize
    });
    if (search && search.length) {
        urlParams.set('search', encodeURIComponent(search));
    }
    return urlParams;
};
```

My input search string is something like this: "name EQ test-1002.dev.net"

However, the result returned is like this:-
https://test.com/cards?page=1&pagesize=10&search=name%2520EQ%2520test-1002.dev.net

It looks like **URLSearchParams** is double encoding the search with %2520 instead of just %20.

How can I add this, but still encode it %20? Could someone please help me out here?

Thanks,
Ashik

Comment: `URLSearchParams` doesn't do it twice, it does it once, but after you do it an additional time with `encodeURIComponent`. You should be able to remove the additional encoding that occurs before setting the value.

Comment: @Chase is right. I'd use `urlParams.set('search', search);` …

Comment: @Chase and JosefZ Simply setting the urlParams.set('search', search) won't work. I've tried this. It does not encode anything. This is the result. It appends + operator:- search=name+EQ+test-1002.dev.net

Comment: The `+` is the encoding for the space character. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-8.2.1

Answer (score 1):

There is no native solution available for this afaik, You can try decoding the string before encoding it again. This will ensure that you are encoding the string once assuming that you passing a non encoded string.

```js
const getUrlParams = (page, pagesize, search) => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams({
        page,
        pagesize
    });
    if (search && search.length) {
        urlParams.set('search', encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(search)));
    }
    return urlParams;
};
```

Comment: I've tried. This doesn't work. The result is the same:-

https://test.com/cards?page=1&pagesize=10&search=name%2520EQ%2520test-1002.dev.net

Comment: Hey could you add a codpen or jsbin link of your exact code?